# Is there a C# static analysis tool for catching APIs that fail to meet functional requirements?

Tags: c#, static-analysis

One of my biggest pet peeves is APIs that don't do what the average user would intuit the API would do.

Case-in-point: .NET's [DateTime.ToUniversalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx).  The documentation is frightening:

> On Windows XP systems, the ToUniversalTime method recognizes only the current adjustment rule when converting from local time to UTC. As a result, conversions for periods before the current adjustment rule came into effect may not accurately reflect the difference between local time and UTC.

And later goes on to say:

> On Windows XP systems, the ToUniversalTime method recognizes only the current adjustment rule for the local time zone, which it applies to all dates, including down-level dates (that is, dates that are earlier than the starting date of the current adjustment rule). **Applications running on Windows XP that require historically accurate local date and time calculations must work around this behavior** by using the FindSystemTimeZoneById method to retrieve a TimeZoneInfo object that corresponds to the local time zone and calling its TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo) method.

This has to be the single most hilarious sentence of documentation ever created.  Who doesn't require accurate local date and time calculations when using ToUniversalTime()?  Why not just mark this method with ObsoleteAttribute?

At any rate, what I am looking for is a tool that I could mark assembly's with assembly-level metadata, such as [RequiresHistoricallyAccurateLocalDateAndTimeCalculationsAttribute].  Then if it finds any instances of ToUniversalTime(), flag them as compiler errors, in the same way that C# wouldn't let me access unmanaged code directly without unsafe annotations.

Comment: Your critique of this example, as well as your first line premise seem to come from a very academic perspective, rather than real world.

Comment: What would the real world perspective be?

Comment: The real world is extremely messy, unfortunately. In the example of XP, time handling standards are changing, the future of computing has changed, methodologies have, are, and continue to change.  There is simply no way to see into the future far enough to anticipate the design requirements such that it will be backwards and forwards compatible in an elegant manner.  In regards to how APIs should behave, "intuitive" behaviors are very dependent on your particular experience.  What *I* expect a program to do may be very different from what *you* expect it to do, purely based on prior experience

Comment: Correct calculations are "intuitive" to real world financial services applications depending on the fidelity of date abstractions, e.g. for reporting cash flows.  Static analysis to catch bad coding practices in mega-million dollar projects, w/ 50+ team members, where I cannot catch by peer code review every use of a double where there should be a decimal, etc. is not simply academic, it's necessary.

Comment: I definitely agree, though in this specific case I think you're conflating correct results with API behavior/structure.  I'm merely commenting on your stated example in the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requirement seems more suited to code analysis rather than attribute decoration or compilation errors.

See: http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/index.html

> This has to be the single most hilarious sentence of documentation
>   ever created. Who doesn't require accurate local date and time
>   calculations when using ToUniversalTime()? Why not just mark this
>   method with ObsoleteAttribute?

Given the nature/complexity of date/time calculation, this isn't a particular frightening/shocking revelation.

If I was doing UTC processing on Windows XP or any other OS, I would first acquaint myself with the idiosyncrasies of the platform just as I would for pretty much any other complex operation. The alternative given (`TimeZoneInfo`) isn't bulletproof either as that is highly dependent on the platform.

With regards to the platform dependence of `TimeZoneInfo`...I'm referring to the OS.

When you start working with time zone conversion (from which many date-related issues originate), you use methods like [FindSystemTimeZoneById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid). On the plus side, the method name makes it clear that you are working with the local system (so perhaps it's less ambiguous than `ToUniversalTime()`). However, the OS is queried for the list of time zones, so it's possible for the OS to return a bad list (I believe in Windows the values live in the registry), the list to be out of date (perhaps a badly patched machine), etc.

I noticed that Windows XP also seems to have [ambiguity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382991) issues with `TimeZoneInfo` (see "Notes to Callers"):

> On Windows XP systems (...) As a result, the method may not accurately report ambiguous time
>   offsets for periods before the current adjustment rule came into
>   effect. For more information, see the Notes for Callers section in the
>   Local property.

And (as you pointed out), the underlying platform implementation might be flawed.

Furthermore, the time zones are referenced by string IDs. While these don't seem to change much, there is still the potential for "magic strings" stored in an application which no longer match a timezone.

At least that's what I've found, though my knowledge of the subject is far from exhaustive. My experience with .Net and universal time on Windows Server has been positive.

**My point is that there is usually a good reason why the BCL (base class library) authors implemented things a certain way, even if it *does* lead to unexpected behavior. The alternative would be to omit the functionality altogether.**

If you have identified this as a pitfall, then I think it's commendable that you are taking the time to mitigate it.

Comment: 1) Thanks for a reasonable do-it-yourself answer.  I have never written my own FxCop rules before, mainly due to lack of documentation on how, and that website you provided is a true gem. 2) When you say platform-dependent, are you referring to Mono or things like Compact Framework, Windows Phone 7, and Silverlight?  In general, I agree, the alternative could be buggy on a different platform or require permissions the user doesn't have.

Comment: Added more detail...in brief, time zone operations usually rely on the OS so they aren't foolproof.

Comment: Thanks for your expanded answer. 1) I found [Coding Best Practices Using DateTime in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx) on MSDN, with a very basic error: conflating GMT and UTC. 2) BCL authors make mistakes.  Here, it's very likely this dependency on the registry left them searching for some kludge to help a customer. 30

Answer (score 1):

Make yourself friends with the FxCop tool. From what I understand, this is what you are looking for. It's a static analysis tool which can be extended with custom rules expressed as a C# code relying on the FxCop API.